# Как разобрать url с помощью expode?

Tags: php

Помогите разобрать `url` на переменные

```
https://vk.com/wall-63361131_174500
```

Нужно в `$groupid` поместить `63361131`,
а в `$postid` поместить `174500`

Comment: если это не задание сделать именно с `explode`, то лучше для этой цели использовать регулярное выражение

Comment: @teran Тоже об этом подумал, но написано при помощи explode((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  $url = "https://vk.com/wall-63361131_174500";
  $id = explode("wall-", $url)[1];

  $groupid = explode("_", $id)[0];
  $postid  = explode("_", $id)[1];
```

Comment: `[,$id] = explode(....)`, `[$groupId, $postId] = explode(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант.

```
$a = strtok(parse_url('https://vk.com/wall-63361131_174500', 5), "-_");
$groupid = strtok("_");
$postid = strtok("-");
```